# Proof that file was sent from my organization?

Tags: security, cryptography

Me and other developers in my office encountered in this scenario :

We are an Insurance company which needs to send files to our customers.

But  we need 2 things :

From The customers Point of view :

1. How can I be sure that this file that was sent to me is from My insurance company ?
2. How can I be sure that this file is the original file that was sent to me ?

---

for 2) i thought that I should use md5 and send it to the users - but this also needs its genuine... so Im in a dead end.

What is the best approach for this ?

**p.s.**
We  don't want to open a virtual drive on our site  - and let each costumer a username and Password.

Comment: What is the technical competence level of the customers in question, are these regular consumers, business consumers, etc. As most good solutions aren't the most user-friendly ones.

Comment: Digitally sign the document as a pdf or sign the email.  Unless you have a certificate there really isn't a way to verify the document.

Comment: 2 answers and nobody noticed this is **not** a programming question?

Comment: @Tomasz Nurkiewicz Its quite a good programming approach Question.

Comment: How are these documents being sent?  Email?  PDFs as attachments?

Comment: @josh3736 either way - for us , it doesnt matter

Comment: @RoyiNamir: I think this is a better fit for another site, *unless* you are planning on rolling this into a program which uses it. Currently the way your question reads and is tagged, it is less about programming and more about a tool to run. There are great PGP UI's available that enable exactly what you want, but SO isn't the place to discuss these.

Comment: @sixlettervariables Which StackExchange site ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) or [IT Security](http://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: suggest moving to http://security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what public key encryption (aka asymmetric encryption) was made for.

You have a public key and a private key.  You give the public key out to anybody you need to send files to.  There is no need to protect this, you could post it on your website.  Anything encrypted using your private key (which is secret) can only be decrypted using the public key.

So if your customers can use your public key to decrypt the file it proves it originated from you since you're the only ones with the private key.

Comment: Lets say I have a file 1.doc which  My company Send to John. I Dont want to encrypt the file ( It will be hard for the John to Decrypt it - he is no computer man) , and of course How can John be sure that it was my company who sent him the file ?

Comment: In which tool John can approve that it was sent by us? ( Is there online tool or exe ?)

Comment: I was mainly focusing on the theory.  To answer the question how does this prove it's from you? Because nobody else knows your private key, so nobody else could have encrypted it such that your public key can decrypt it.

Comment: As somebody else mentioned this tech is usually applied in the form of a digital signature.  This is done by essentially taking a hash of the document, then encrypting that hash using your private key.  The the customer can use a tool that decrypts the hash using your public key, and checks if the hash matches the document.  Adobe Acrobat/Reader supports digital signing on PDF files I believe.

Comment: Thank you for your effort : Still 2 quetions please : 1) so What your Saying Is that our site should Expose (in public) the Public Key. and We can send the file to john ( un-encrypted) with md5 String which is encrypted by our Private Key. correct ?

Comment: Yup, thats the gist of how digital signing works.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4624/discussion-between-royi-namir-and-dylan-smith)

Comment: You shouldn't implement this yourself - use existing software, like PGP, to do it.

Comment: http://www.adobe.com/security/digsig.html is what you are looking for, if you use ADOBE pdf as your document medium.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need **Pretty Good Privacy**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy

Comment: I like PGP, but realistically, how many insurance customers will even have PGP/GPG or know how to use it properly?  (*I* don't even have the software installed.)  I'd wager less than a percentage point.

Comment: @josh3736: the OP asked for "proof" not "best effort for the technically challenged".

Comment: @josh3736 - how many insurance companies are sending their clients documents in a manner that would make this even required.  My car insurance digitally signs its documents.

Comment: @sixlettervariables, what good is a system if none of your users are able to use it?

Comment: @Ramhound, I never said digitally signing documents was a bad idea; in fact, I think it's something everyone I do business with should be doing.  My point was that the signature validation method needs to be easy -- and ideally built-in to client software that is already on end user machines.  PGP isn't.

Comment: @Ramhound Lets say your Car Company sent you 1.doc.  In which tool you can approve that it was sent by them ? ( Is there online tool or exe ?)

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about email, take a look at digitally signing the email with [S/MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S/MIME).  You use a certificate issued by a CA (much like SSL), which proves both that your organization sent the email and that its contents have not been altered.

S/MIME validation support is built in to many email clients, including Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cryptographically sign the files somehow, and the customers need to have a way of verifying these signatures. There are plenty of ways:

- PGP
- S/MIME
- Distribution via HTTPS.

Do get this right, you have to think about what you are trying to protect, and what it is worth to you and to the customer to protect it. Is it the authenticity of the file when it is stored at the users computer? Do you want to avoid customers tampering with the file? Do you want to avoid someone tampering with the file before it gets to the user?

If the data you want to share is text documents, Adobe has support for [signed pdf files](http://www.adobe.com/security/digsig.html). That might be worth examining.

Comment: Lets say I have a file 1.doc which My company Send to John. I Dont want to encrypt the file ( It will be hard for the John to Decrypt it - he is no computer man) , and of course How can John be sure that it was my company who sent him the file ? Does the file Has to be Encryprted ? ( if its john's grandmother - she wont be able to read the file)  - Still how can John be sure that it was us who sent john the Email ?

Comment: If you want John (but not his grandmother) to be able to read the file then you definitely need to go the PKI path and make sure you have a unique encryption key for John.